# Expand subshell before executing it?

Tags: bash, shell, command-history, subshell

I often run commands using subshells, and sometimes would like to have the subshells expanded before I run something.. This way I could verify what I'm doing, and possibly edit what's about to happen as well.

For example, how can I get the following command line to be expanded before I run it, so I can edit the results of the subshell?

e.g.

```
$ find -name "test.txt" 
/tmp/test.txt

$ mv $(!!) /tmp/new.txt
```

I'd like to see the subshell expanded *before* I run the command, like so:

```
$ mv /tmp/test.txt /tmp/new.txt
```

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: zsh can do this, but I'm fairly certain bash cannot. In zsh if you have your cursor on the parameter, and hit TAB, it'll expand it

Comment: I've since switched to `zsh` and it's great and does this, as you suggest... nice tip! I'll leave the original answer here, as it was a `bash` question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`shell-expand-line` (`\e\C-e`) expands command substitutions in bash.

```
$ bind -p|grep shell-ex
"\e\C-e": shell-expand-line
```

`$(!!)\e\C-e` would run the previous command again and insert the output:

```
"\eo": "$(!!)\e\C-e"
```

It also expands other command substitutions, but there is no command like `shell-expand-word`.

In bash 4.0 or later you could also enable `globstar`, type `**/file.txt`, and use `glob-complete-word` (`\eg`) or `glob-expand-word` (`\C-x*`).

Answer (score 3):

Here’s a handy trick — add this line to ~/.inputrc (creating the file if necessary):

> Control-x: shell-expand-line

Note you could also either of the following to expand only history, or your aliases, or both:

> Control-x: history-expand-line

or

> Control-x: alias-expand-line

or

> Control-x: history-and-alias-expand-line

This was gleaned [from this blog](http://taint.org/2005/05/04/004902a.html), and [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/247770/how-to-expand-aliases-inline-in-bash), which is very similar: