# Display alias with substitutions

Tags: bash, alias, macos

Is there a way to display aliases *after* bash has made the substitutions?

**Background:**
I have a long alias that performs actions on a directory.

```
alias do_it='cd my_working_dir; do_stuff'
```

This works fine, but the alias is quite long and `my_working_dir` changes often.  Rather than do a in-depth search on my alias for all occurrences of `my_working_dir`, I changed to this:

```
MY_WORKING_DIR=some_dir
alias do_it='cd ${MY_WORKING_DIR}; do_stuff'
```

This works fine.

However, sometimes I want to make slight changes to the alias on the fly.  With the previous alias construction, I was able to type `alias`, copy/paste the command I wanted, make mods and execute.  Using this substitution, when I type `alias` I get:

```
do_it='cd ${MY_WORKING_DIR}; do_stuff'
```

Now I have to manually replace `MY_WORKING_DIR`.  Is there a handy way to get a copy of the alias **after** bash has made the substitutions (in this case the substitution for `${MY_WORKING_DIR}`.

**Clarification**:
My goal is not change the inputs to the alias/function.  I wish to display the resulting alias/function **with substitutions already made** so that I can copy/paste that output to make more complex commands.
I have yet to find a way to display either aliases or functions with the substitutions already made.

**Additional Example**

```
TARGET_DIR='my_dir'    
alias do_it='cd ${TARGET_DIR}; run task; echo "Task done in ${TARGET_DIR}'
```

```
alias
```

```
do_it='cd ${TARGET_DIR}; run task; echo "Task done in ${TARGET_DIR}'
```

If I want to repeat the alias 50x, I could copy the alias output, then paste it into the following line:

```
for i in {1..50}; do <paste_here>; done
```

But that won't work because the `alias` output has left ${TARGET_DIR} unresolved.

Using a function instead of an alias does not work either because `declare` likewise does not replace ${TARGET_DIR}.

This is a simplified example.  The real aliases I am using are long and tedious, with ${TARGET_DIR} occurring many times, so while the alias/function works great, composing the alias output into more complex on-the-fly commands requires me to manually replace ${TARGET_DIR} multiple times.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't make this a shell function instead, with the directory as an argument (possibly with a default value)?

Comment: The only reason would be aliases are easier to implement.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll try using a function instead.

Comment: I still don't understand what it is you want to do. Sorry.

Comment: In your "Additional Example", you want to run the alias 50 times, each time with another `TARGET_DIR` value?  That's literally what turning it into a function that takes the directory as an argument would allow you to do (see the end of my answer below). In fact, since the alias uses `$TARGET_DIR` unresolved, just changing this variable's value and calling the alias again would probably also work, although using a function would allow you to handle quoting better.

Comment: No, $TARGET_DIR is just the repository I'm working out of at the time.  It changes every few days or so.  The directory name is a hash of the git branch name.  The whole point is to avoid typing in the long directory name each time.  I want to change it in the .bashrc every once in a while and have all my aliases working and copy/pastable on the fly.  Displaying functions doesn't resolve substitutions any better than displaying aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of:

[how to expand aliases inline in bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/247770/how-to-expand-aliases-inline-in-bash)

and

[Expand subshell before executing it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73644/expand-subshell-before-executing-it)

Turns out, BASH uses readline to handle this.  Just press <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>

To test, I have the following alias defined in my .bash_profile:

```
alias cdh='cd ${HOME}'
```

Starting a new shell/terminal allows me to type:

`cdh`

Then press:
<kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>

and readline updates the command-line to:

```
cd /home/user_name
```

MacOS 13.2.1
iterm2 3.4.15
bash 5.1.8(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21.2.0)

Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears you want to change the working directory every once in a while, a suggestion would be to replace the alias with a shell function, which could take the directory pathname as a command line argument:

```bash
do_it () {
    local wd="${1:-my_working_dir}"
    cd "$wd" || return
    do_stuff
 }
```

This function takes an optional single argument, a directory pathname.  If given, the function's local `wd` variable is set to this value. If not given, the local `wd` variable is set to the static string `my_working_dir`.

With a small change, you could disallow the function from leaving the user in an unexpected working directory:

```bash
do_it () {
    local wd="${1:-my_working_dir}"
    (
        cd "$wd" || return
        do_stuff
    )
 }
```

The parenthesised subshell's environment inside the function (which includes the current working directory, possibly modified by `cd`) would not affect the environment of the calling shell.

You would declare this function wherever you usually declare aliases, and you would use it either as

```bash
do_it
```

or with an argument,

```bash
do_it some/directory/path
```

or, in a loop that runs it over a number of directory pathnames,

```bash
for target_dir in some/pattern/dir*/
do
    do_it "$target_dir"
done
```

Comment: How would I display the resulting commands so that I could cut and paste them into new commands?

Comment: @JS. I'm not quite sure I understand. Why would you want to do that? According to the question, the only thing you wanted to change was to use another directory.

Comment: @JS. It's quite possible that I've misunderstood what it is you want to accomplish. It would be good if you could clarify this in your question by showing more in-depth examples.

Comment: @JS. That sounds like [an XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please ask about your problem or what you are trying to accomplish instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not really that I know, at least not in a safe and generic way. That also seems like an extremely strange way of using aliases to me.

Are you sure a shell script wouldn't be more appropriate? Something placed on your `$PATH` (adjust `$PATH` if needed) and named `do_it`, that may take arguments.

You could also have that script do the same actions as your alias, and display the alias command with substitutions if asked.

---

If you insist on aliases, this is exremely unsafe as you risk expanding more than you want, mishandle escape characters like `\`, etc, but you could do something similar to:

```
$ alias test='echo $UID'
$ alias xalias='f(){ eval echo $(echo $(alias "$@" | sed s,\'\'',\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\'',g ) ) ; unset -f f; }; f'
$ xalias test
alias test='echo 1000'
```

Getting the quotations right was an exercise in frustration. This works by quoting the single quotes: `'` -> `\'`, then quoting all of that again. The first `eval` call unquotes a level, and at that point, the `${VAR}` are not quoted, so they are evaluated. Then `echo` adds back the quotation marks, as the string is evaluated in a subshell. I may have overcomplexified a bit due to the number of indirections.

That's still quite brittle, and bash+sed is a bad fit for this job.